# Как проверить "пойманные" клавиши (hooked keys) в C#?

Tags: c#, hook

Пишу простую (со своей стороны) программу, она состоит из готового пакета [KeystrokeAPI](https://github.com/fabriciorissetto/KeystrokeAPI), который ловит нажатые клавиши и выводит их на консоль, так вот проблема в том, что я никак не могу создать проверку клавиши, мне вот например надо ,чтобы при нажатии клавиши **"a"** программа выключалась.

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string help = "" ;

        using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
        {

            api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => { help = character.ToString(); });


            Start();


        }

        void Start()
        {
            while (Console.ReadLine() != "exit")
                {                  
                Console.WriteLine(help);
                if (CheckSymbol("a"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Функция проверки
        bool CheckSymbol(string symb)
        {
            if (symb == "a")
            { return true; }
            else
            { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

Возвращается character же в виде String, так почему он не может проверить данный символ, если он там действительно есть!

Проблема не в ReadLine()! А само условие неправильно построено, почему-то не проверяет.

```
      void Start()
     {
         while (true)
            {
            Console.ReadKey();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (CheckSymbol("a"))
            {
                break;
            }
          }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы используете `Console.ReadLine()`, которое считывает строку, а не символ. А на скрине у вас незавершенный ввд строки

Comment: Вопрос не об этом, условия не считывается, даже поменяв основной цикл, проверка символа не работает. (обновил)

Comment: Брейкпоинты ставили? В дебагере запускали?

Comment: Все эти действия нужны с целью того ,чтобы отследить машинный код символа? Простите за нубство.

Comment: по сути да, вы можете останавливать процесс выполнения вашей программы, смотреть какая строка в данный момент выполняется, и прочие вещи делать чтобы разобраться почему ваш код работает именно так, как работает

Comment: Удобная вещь, спасибо , буду разбираться с этим. Но геттер character отлично конвертится в String , и выводится соответствующе в консоль, нельзя как-то без деббагов и машинных кодов в этом разобраться? Т.е. получить значение строки с переменной, метод contains (char) тоже не может найти там символа, хотя в консоль выводится нормально, у меня, как новичка в программировании - МОЗГ просто ГОРИТ :-))

Comment: приведите полный код программы, без сторонних библиотек типа `KeystrokeAPI`, который у вас работает не так, как вы ожидаете